# How to make a tab expend?

Tags: watir

Here is the website I want to try out. 
http://www.csun.edu/
Under myNorthRidge Portal, there is a place for me to fill out my user id and password. But the thing is that I have to click on the "sign" to expand the tab first. I could not find a way to get around this problem :( ? Anyone could share me a hint how to solve this problem? Thanks
This is the html tag for it:

```
<div class="CollapsiblePanelTab">Log In</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I got it solved ;) by using element_by_xpath( "..." )

```
ie.element_by_xpath( "/html/body/div/div[5]/div/div" ).click
```

Comment: You can also accept your own answer, if you solved the problem yourself. This will make it easier to spot for other people that come here with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
browser.div(:text => "Log In").click
```

Comment: Thanks Zeljko ;) ! Another cool solution ! I'm in love with Ruby now ^_^ !

Comment: I am glad you like Ruby and Watir. :)